# How to set NSMuteableURLRequest connection to "Connection: close"?

Tags: connection, nsmutableurlrequest

I have tried setting  setting my NSMuteableURLRequest to close , but its always on 'keep-alive' , how can I force to close connection. I am doing like this :

```
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url ];  
[req setHTTPBody: [postStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 
[req setValue:@"close" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Connection"];
```

And how bad it is if connections stays on 'keep-alive' ?
Thanks for your help.